# Two column bibliography for 'report' class

Tags: latex, bibliography

I am new to LATEX and I am currently writing my project thesis for my B.tech degree in LATEX using TeXstudio and MiKTeX. I got stuck in printing my bibliography in the last section of the report in two columns as the list is very big and consumes lot of page. Following is my code in tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
     \begin{multicols}{2}
          \printbibliography
     \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and my '**reference.bib**' contains following texts:

```
@article{4,
    author = {Dhillon, Ankita and Nair, Manjula and Kumar, Dinesh},
    doi = {10.1039/c6ay01534d},
    issn = {17599679},
    journal = {Analytical Methods},
    number = {27},
    pages = {5338--5352},
    title = {{Analytical methods for determination and sensing of fluoride in biotic and abiotic sources: A review}},
    volume = {8},
    year = {2016}
}
@article{ICP,
    author = {Fulford, J. E. and Quan, E. S.K.},
    doi = {10.1366/0003702884428040},
    issn = {00037028},
    journal = {Applied Spectroscopy},
    number = {3},
    pages = {425--428},
    title = {{Negative Ions in Inductively Coupled Plasma Mass Spectrometry.}},
    volume = {42},
    year = {1988}
}
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords = "physics"
}
......
```

What result I am getting looks like:
[What I am getting (I don't want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFqap.png)
Second column is going little bit higher than the title '**References**'. Which I want to avoid.

But what I desired is:
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9szsG.png)
Please help me get that second column first element to be aligned with first column first element.

---

### Using '\twocolumn' for the same purpose

Alternatively, I tried just `\twocolumn` command as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
     \twocolumn
     \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now I got the formeting I require as follows:
[result with \twocolumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zwbu.png)

But problem with [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zwbu.png) is that few sentences in the first column is breaking as it reaches the column end and it enters the send column. Is there any way to wrap the sentences of the first column which is going out of first column and reaching the second column.

Comment: Unfortunately the fragment of the bib file you show in your question does not allow us to reproduce the problem with the `\twocolumn` solution. The problem is probably caused by too narrow columns which make it difficult for tex to find suitable break points. Maybe `\twocolumn
     \raggedright
     \printbibliography` is worth a try...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for your comment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried, it works pretty well this time. But if I use your way (two column bibliography), it takes more pages than single column bibliography takes due to lot of empty spaces in  two column bibliography (using \raggedright). It is unnecessary. Any way, thanks for valuable comment.

Comment: The bibliography generated by biblatex in one column is already pretty compact, introducing two columns and loosing the space between them won't magically fit more text on the same space

Comment: instead of focusing on the number of pages, I think it should be more important to make your document pleasant to read for your readers ... I don't think a two column bibliography will help with this goal